# Why did they use two separate vectors to calculate the magnitude and angle of the initial velocity?

Tags: velocity, projectile, speed

The question/solution are on the attached images. (It's dealing with projectile motion)

I already understand how to work out part a, but I'm having trouble understanding why they used the final velocity vector in part b if the questions asks for the magnitude of the initial velocity.

Wouldn't we just use v0x and v0y in part b also? (Since they want the magnitude of the initial velocity)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it's just a mistake in the textbook.